# Flux.concatDelayError with short-circuit option

Tags: project-reactor

I was using `Flux.concatDelayError` because I want to subscribe to multiple `Monos` one by one, and also want to know if something has failed.

However, now I would also like to short-circuit if one of my `Monos` completes with a specific type of error.
Is this possible easily?

Comment: What you need is a simple concat operator I believe.

Comment: @MartinTarjányi How would that delay and signal the the errors at the end?

Comment: @MartinTarjányi That would be the case for short-circuiting if a `Mono` completed with *any* type of error, but it's not immediately obvious how that could be used to just short-circuit a *specific* type of error.

Comment: @MichaelBerry I missed that point. I posted a potential solution. Not sure if that's a viable solution for the poster's problem.

Answer (score 2):

Using `onErrorResume` operator, you could configure a conditional fallback to `Mono.empty()` for each Mono:

```java
package com.example;

import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import static java.util.function.Predicate.not;

public class ReactorExample
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Mono<String> mono = Mono.just("first").doOnNext(a -> System.out.println(a + " was called."));

        Mono<String> mono2 = Mono.<String>error(new RuntimeException("Not terminating error."))
                .onErrorResume(not(ShortCircuitingException.class::isInstance), e -> Mono.empty());

        Mono<String> mono3 = Mono.just("third").doOnNext(a -> System.out.println(a + " was called."));

        Mono<String> mono4 = Mono.<String>error(new ShortCircuitingException())
                                 .onErrorResume(not(ShortCircuitingException.class::isInstance), e -> Mono.empty());

        Mono<String> mono5 = Mono.just("fifth").doOnNext(a -> System.out.println(a + " was called."));

        Flux.concat(mono, mono2, mono3, mono4, mono5)
            .collectList()
            .block();
    }

    private static class ShortCircuitingException extends RuntimeException
    {
    }
}
```

Output:

```
first was called.
third was called.
Exception in thread "main" com.example.ReactorExample$ShortCircuitingException
```

Comment: I also had this idea, but this doesn't have an error delaying capability. In this example if I had only `mono` and `mono2` I would like to know about the `RuntimeException` at the end of the flow.

Comment: @jakk why do you need to know about the error? if just for logging you can put doOnError for the Monos?